# NiFi - Sending binary files to Rest API?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I've been trying to send a file that is currently in base64 to an API that only accepts binary data.

The process I'm using is the following:

1. I get the file with a processor in a JSON with it's filename and content type.
2. I use an EvaluateJsonPath (destination=content) to stores evaluated base64 into the flowfile content.
3. Base64EncodeContent (decode) decodes base64 content into a binary. I assume this is how this processor works, first time using it as "decode".
4. I prepare the headers specific for my request and send everything to an InvokeHTTP.

I keep getting a Bad Request all the time.

Any ideas?

Comment: i bet you are setting incorrect parameters in InvokeHTTP because everything else looks good